# What should be optimal gas limit and gas price for 80 addresses airdrop?

Tags: gas-limit, out-of-gas, gas-price, gas-estimate, airdrop

This is my airdrop function:

```
mapping (address => bool) public airdrops;
function airdropTokens(address[] _recipient, uint256[] _tokens) public onlyOwner{
uint airdropped;
for(uint256 i = 0; i< _recipient.length; i++)
{
      airdrops[_recipient[i]] = true;
      require(token.transferFrom(msg.sender, _recipient[i], _tokens[i] * decimalFactor));
      airdropped = airdropped.add(_tokens[i] * decimalFactor);
}
```

}

What should be optimal gas limit and gas price for this? I initially used, gasPrice = 50000000000 and gasLimit = 4500000, which works out at $47.27. Is this normal? I managed to successfully send a batch of 20 addresses at 3.5 GWEI / 2500000 Gas limit see: [airdrop to 20 addresses transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xa905746cad48affd485d4e2ce16a5a1c91c77587b58e0ee681a9a518c3ead0fe)

But for other batch of 80 addresses, it failed at 4 GWEI / 4500000 Gas limit, see [link here](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x2198d21810944b001564c6d7a0a8947f530d745e4d740ebdb659804fb8240251)
Any ideas on how to manage the gas better? If I was to send out the 350 more batches at the recommended prices, it would cost me around £16k!!

P.S: Currently, each airdrop transaction is sending tokens to 80 addresses at once.

Comment: @Rob Hitchens B9lab Can u please see if that is something you can answer?

Comment: One problem with your airdrop is that for every recipient you are consuming an extra slot with `airdrops[_recipient[i]] = true;`, you pay 20k gas to store a single bit. From the successful transaction you use around 125k gas per token transfer which seems a bit high. I'd take a look at to optimize transferFrom.

Comment: the storage of receipient record can be compromised. Would you suggest omitting it will help me ? How much gas cost you think it'll save per transaction and for 80?

Comment: In your code the mapping `airdrops` is never used again, but if you use it in another function then you should keep it. Rounding numbers 20k x 80 =1600k = 1.6m.

Answer (score 1):

Here are few hints:

1. replace `public` modifier with `external` in your contract. Here is [why](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.21/contracts.html#visibility-and-getters)
2. Not used gas (limit) is returned back to you so you may put as much as possible. On time of writing it's around 6-7M.
3. You may put low gas price (e.g. 1 GWEI). However, your transaction will take some time. You may estimate it here: https://ethgasstation.info/

Comment: Thanks, since I have already deployed contract onto the main network so how much you think the first point will add benefit? If it will worth alot, I will go about re-deploying.

Comment: I think it worth redeploying, you may experiment on rinkeby to see benefits. gas limit won't save you funds. If you specify too low gas limit it will just burn. If you want to use an existing contract you may only decrease gas price @FarihaAbbasi

Comment: Thanks so Im looking towards, re-deploying contract with usage of "external" and then If I use 4500000 gas limit and 2 Gwei gas Price, would you suggest is it all a good combination for airdrop to 80 addresses? I ran into "Out of gas" exception while transferring to 80 addresses with 4 GWEI and 4500000 Gas limit. So you think, I will not get this issue again?

Comment: Out of gas is because of low gas limit. When you use external it should be lower. I cannot tell you the exact price you should experiment. I would put 6M to be safe. You may deploy to test network to experiment http://rinkeby.etherscan.io

Comment: I made the necessary changing to the contract, re-deployed, used 4500000 gas limit and 1 Gwei on ropsten test network, it worked fine. On main net, my transaction took more than 8-9 hours and finally dropped. see [link](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x6e7adcf70e603c4e9d0f95e059f613ea44cd6e9c80151b00eab5c07d68ee6b7c)

Comment: tried two more time, with 5Gwei and 4Gwei but they failed. see [5gwei link](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xfb388a11a3fc11ec3079c45ce32c3d31acc6f2d033b5f29cd99b9f2f13e021bb) [4gwei link](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xb1f6615c895535f72cf994d30644a1e1817375e5dbe6e7e1c64db4b381112d31)

Comment: @FarihaAbbasi ok, let me clarify one more time. Please put gasPrice: 1.5 GWEI, gasLimit: 6000000 (6M), and try to airdrop 100 accounts. The reason you burn transaction is not because gas price. It's because gas limit. When you put gas limit low & transaction needs more it just burns all of your gas. Better put more, remaining will be returned to you. Gas price only influence how fast transaction will be executed. If 6M is not enough you may decrease number of addresses in airdrop untill it's ok.

Comment: @petro.sidlovskyy Using a large gas limit is not optimal if you are in a hurry, miners tend to skip transactions with large gas limit a low gas price.